# Error after deactivating Publishing Infrastructure Feature

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint 2010 site migrated from MOSS 2007. It uses German language pack. Here Pages library name is 'Seiten'. When Publishing Infrastructure Feature is activated everything works fine. The moment I deactivate Publishing Infrastructure feature I get following error while visiting home page:

```
Liste nicht vorhanden.

Die gewählte Seite verweist auf eine nicht vorhandene Liste. Möglicherweise wurde sie von einem anderen Benutzer gelöscht. (List not available.
```

> The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have
>   been deleted by another user.)

Home page is stored in pages library 'Seiten'. I verified web.Properties '__PagesListId' and '__PagesListName' is set to 'Seiten' library Id and name.

I tried this workaround provided my Microsoft but it didn't help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2484317

Please let me know if you have any suggestions solving this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you used the publishing template in 2007, in order to work site properly you need publishing feature activated. If you deactivate it then it will remove certain pages/library from site collection.

As you mentioned when you activate it then everything work as expected. So the Big Question is, why you want to deactivate the publishing feature?